# How to run the same nunit tests with different preconditions? (fixtures)

Tags: c#, nunit

I have set of tests and have to run it with two different SetUp in base class.

Here is screenshot [image: http://screencast.com/t/G150W2P4o]

How can I improve it?

Comment: If they need different setups then you should implement a method marked with the `SetupAttribute`.

Comment: Is it possible to have two setup fixtures? Some kind of hierarchy?

Comment: Sure it is. Every class can be a `TestFixture`. Do you have problems on this? Can´t see any error here.

Comment: Now I need to duplicate my test sets, for example you can see on screenshot what  I added test "BlockAdvancedFIlters_Verify.." twice - one for logged scenario and second for unlogged. It is very hard to maintain this sets of tests.

Comment: As in every usual class be aware of copy-pasting code as it will become a maintenance-horror. Extract a common class that does the work you need to be done in both tests and refrence that class wthin the fixtures. Alternativly or in addition use parameterized tests as suggested from Charlie in his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a single, parameterized test fixture. Pass in information about which setup (probably OneTimeSetUp) should be used to each instance of the fixture. The information will have to be constant values like strings so that it can be used as an argument to the attribute.

For example...

```
   [TestFixture("setup1", 5)]
   [TestFixture("setup2", 9)]
   public class MyTestFixture
   {
      public MyTestFixture(string setup, int counter)
      {
         // You can save the arguments, or do something 
         // with them and save the result in instance members
      }

      [Test]
      public void SomeTest()
      {
         // Do what you need to do, using the arguments
      }
   }
```